# Why are “$\sin x -x \cos x$” and “$\sin x - x$” not equal when x tends to $0$?

Tags: limits

\begin{align*}
\lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{1}{{x^2}} - \cot^2{x}\right) &= \lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2·\cos^2 x}{x^4}\right) \\
  &= \lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin x+x·\cos x}{x}\right)·\lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin x-x·\cos x}{x^3}\right) \\
  &= 2\lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin x-x·\cos x}{x^3}\right) \\
  &=2\lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\cos x-(\cos x-x·\sin x)}{3x^2}\right) \\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{1}{{x^2}} - \cot^2{x}\right) &= \lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2·\cos^2 x}{x^4}\right) \\
  &= \lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin x+x·\cos x}{x}\right)·\lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin x-x·\cos x}{x^3}\right) \\
  &= 2\lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin x-x·\cos x}{x^3}\right) \\
  &=2\lim_{{x \to 0}} \left(\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}

As $x$ tends to $0$, $\cos x$ is $1$. Shouldn't the equations $\sin x -x \cos x = \sin x - x$ also hold? Why did it turn out to be a different answer?

Comment: Do you believe that if $f(0)=g(0)$, then $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3}$ must equal $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{g(x)}{x^3}$? That's not the case.

Comment: How did the denominator of $x^2$become $x^4$ in the first line?

Answer (score 3):

You have to consider the higher terms of the expansion of the cosine function:
$$\sin x-x\cos x\sim x-x^3/6-x(1-x^2/2)=x^3/3 $$
whereas
$$\sin x-x \sim -x^3/6$$